# Is there a Visual Studio 2022 .Net 6.0 compatible version of Microsoft.Express.Drawing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create a WPF custom control circular progressbar.

Earlier versions of .Net would support the Microsoft.Expression.Drawing nuget package download which made Arc creation really simple.

I am developing with Visual Studio 2022 and .Net 6.0 .

If I try to download the Microsoft.Expression.Drawing nuget package, an error message is produced saying that some parts of the package are not compatible.

Is there a viable substitution?

Comment: `Microsoft.Expression.Drawing` has been unlisted from Nuget completely so I would advise you look to somewhere else completely.

Comment: Maybe this package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk.WPF/1.0.1?_src=template it contains System.Expression.Drawing dll and support newer .NET versions (but not .NET 6)

Comment: Thanks I definitely understand that fact.  Is there another package that provides the same functionality that is compatible with .Net 6.0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's baked in now if you take a look at the [WPF to .NET6 migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-wpf-framework) guide.

At least some of the blend namespaces are included.

Answer (score 0):

[NetCore5.0.Microsoft.Expression.Drawing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetCore5.0.Microsoft.Expression.Drawing/) nuget package